# Как работают визуальные редакторы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно поставить этот [редактор](http://kwolfy.github.io/KEmoji/) со смайлами на сайт, для добавления комментария. Но он использует `div`. А на сайте комментарий отправляется только с `textarea`. Как отправлять содержимое этого `div`?

Так добавляется комментарий на сайте.

```
<div class="fast-addc-area">
   <textarea rows="3"></textarea>
   <button class="flat xl blue">Добавить</button>
</div>

.on('click','.fast-addc-area button',function(e){
    var shortcomm = $(this).parents('.shortcomm');
    $.post(dle_root+"engine/mods/shortcomm/add.php",{id:shortcomm.find('a').data('id'),comments:$('.fast-addc-area textarea').val()},function(d){
        var cd = d.split("::");
        if(cd[0]=='.') alert(cd[1]);
        else{
            $('.fast-addc-area').fadeOut( 500,function(){$(this).remove()});
            shortcomm.before(d);
            $(".slowcadd").fadeIn(500).removeClass('slowcadd');
        }
    })
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Переделанный код по первому ответу, но сообщение не отправляется.

```
$(document).on('click','.shortcomm a',function(e){
    $(".fast-addc-area").remove();            
    $(this).after('<div class="fast-addc-area"><div id="myEmojiField" contenteditable="true"></div><button class="flat xl blue">Добавить</button><span class="fclose">Отмена</span></div>');

   var kemoji = KEmoji.init('myEmojiField', {
        height: 80
    });   

    $(".fast-addc-area").fadeIn(500);
    e.preventDefault();    
})    
.on('click','.fclose',function(){
    $('.fast-addc-area').fadeOut( 500,function(){$(this).remove()});
    $(this).remove();
})
.on('click','.fast-addc-area button',function(e){
    var shortcomm = $(this).parents('.shortcomm');
    $.post(dle_root+"engine/mods/shortcomm/add.php",{id:shortcomm.find('a').data('id'),comments:kemoji.getValue(KEmoji.HTML_VALUE)},function(d){
        var cd = d.split("::");
        if(cd[0]=='.') alert(cd[1]);
        else{
            $('.fast-addc-area').fadeOut( 500,function(){$(this).remove()});
            shortcomm.before(d);
            $(".slowcadd").fadeIn(500).removeClass('slowcadd');
        }
    })
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- <textarea rows="3"></textarea>
+ <div id="myEmojiField"></div>

- $.post(dle_root+"engine/mods/shortcomm/add.php",{id:shortcomm.find('a').data('id'),comments:$('.fast-addc-area textarea').val()},function(d){
+ $.post(dle_root+"engine/mods/shortcomm/add.php",{id:shortcomm.find('a').data('id'),comments:kemoji.getValue(KEmoji.HTML_VALUE)},function(d){

* kemoji - объект инициализации, см. документацию
```

Comment: Не отправляется сообщение.

Comment: @СергейЛапшин, обычно нельзя поправить код просто механически заменив строчки, нужно понимать что к чему и к чему это приведёт. Так что не видя всей картины в целом, никто не гарантирует правильную работу. В предоставленном куске кода всё, что надо, заменил, но нет гарантии что где-то ещё старый код есть. Для таких дел нанимайте фрилансера.

Comment: Больше нет ничего только php файл.